# How to access file system in os by IE 7, and 8 browser ,without using ActiveXObject?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, activexobject, file-access

How to create a file or list the files in the folder in java script in IE7 and IE8.In general to access the file system in OS , java script uses ActiveXObject. But I need to access the file system **not by ActiveXObject** but by any other ways.

**If I use ActiveXObject** for access means,whenever access going to be happen each time a **pop-up will appear** that **asks the user whether to allow or not ActiveXobject**.It is little **difficult one to client when dy faces this pop-up each time.**

Is thr any Java script API exist to access the file system without use of ActiveXObject or any technique exist to do these things....?

I have to implement file system access applicaion in IE7 and IE8

If any one know kindly share ur knowledge.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: is the application going to be used in enterprise environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no ways in IE7/IE8 without browser plug-ins to access the local computer's file system because doing so is a major security risk and those browsers don't support any of the more modern ways of handling files.

You might get better ideas if you explain what actual problem you're really trying to solve rather than something as generic as your current question.

If this is an enterprise environment, you may be able to prewire some ActiveX settings in the enterprise browsers to allow your ActiveX plug-in to run without prompting.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight can have evaluated trust in browser applications in version 5
for First time it will ask user ( I've not tested it yet )
Notice that users must have installed Silverlight before then you can develop your own app by C#